On the calculation of the first m generalized eigenvectors
This is a classic generalized eigenvalue/eigenvector problem:
$$
A\,\vec{x}=\lambda\,B\,\vec{x}
$$
which, however, is characterized by:

$A,B$ are real, symmetric and positive definite matrices of order $n$;

$(\lambda_i,\vec{x}_i)$ with $i=1,2,\dots,m\le n$ must be such that $\vec{x}_i^t A\,\vec{x}_i=1$.


Therefore, in Mathematica writing:
{m, n} = {15, 50};

A = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {n, n}];
B = RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {n, n}];

A = Transpose[A].A;
B = Transpose[B].B;

{val, vec} = Eigensystem[{A, B}, m];
Do[x = Transpose[{vec[[i]]}];
   vec[[i]] = x / Sqrt[Transpose[x].A.x][[1, 1]], {i, m}];

I get what I want. On the other hand, since I can't use Eigensystem, my best is:
val = Table[0, m];
vec = Table[0, m];
x = Table[1, {n}, {1}];

U = Inverse[B].A;
V = A.U;

Do[Do[y = U.x;
      Do[y = y - vec[[k]].Transpose[vec[[k]]].V.x, {k, i - 1}];
      x = y / (y[[1, 1]] + 10^-15), {j, 500}];
   val[[i]] = (U.x)[[1, 1]] / x[[1, 1]];
   vec[[i]] = x / Sqrt[Transpose[x].A.x][[1, 1]], {i, m}];

which although it "works" I would really like to avoid matrix inversion, find a more intelligent stopping criterion and avoid writing $10^{-15}$ as the denominator to avoid up null denominators.
Can you advise/show me how to do it? Thank you!

Why can't you use EigenSystem?

You can avoid inverting the entire matrix $B$ and instead deal only with triangular inversions/solves. Since $B$ is spd, it admits a Cholesky decomposition $B = LL^T$, where $L$ is lower triangular and nonsingular. Now define $y = L^Tx$. The eigenproblem can now be rewritten as
$$
\begin{aligned}
Ax&=\lambda Bx\\
A(L^{-T}L^T)x &= \lambda LL^Tx \\
L^{-1}AL^{-T}(L^Tx) &= \lambda (L^Tx) \\
Cy &=\lambda y,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $C = L^{-1}AL^{-T}$ is a symmetric matrix. You can solve this using any eigensolver you like then solve the triangular system $L^Tx = y$ to obtain the eigenvalues of the initial problem.
